# Lua nested table get all elements from table if element in table is set to True

Tags: lua, nested-table, lua-5.3

```
Fruits = { apple = { ordered = true, amount = 10 }}
```

i have several different kinds of fruits in this table and i need to output everything where ordered=true to make it look like this:

```
apple ordered: true | apple amount: 10
```

Made it like this

```
for a,b in pairs(Fruits) do
   for c,d in pairs(b) do
      if (d == true) then
         print(a..” ordered: ”..tostring(d)..” | “..a..” amount: “..tostring(d)..”)
      end
   end
end
```

but the output is this

```
apple ordered: true | apple amount: true
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you're looping over the "properties" of each fruit. Thus you have `c = "ordered"` and `d = true` inside the loop. Printing `d` twice will lead to the output you have described. Here's the fixed code:

```lua
for name, props in pairs(Fruits) do
    if props.ordered then
        print(name .. " ordered: true | amount: " .. props.amount)
    end
end
```